# La restricción es que no deben existir tres números iguales ubicados de forma horizontal o vertical en una secuencia directa en una matriz?

Tags: java, matrices

Como le pondría la condición en la matriz q no se repita 3 números iguales en la fila y columna.

```
private int ancho;
    private int largo;
    private int numColores;
    private int[][]datos;
    
    public Creacion(int ancho,int largo,int numColores) {
        this.ancho=ancho;
        this.largo=largo;
        this.numColores=numColores;
        datos=new int[this.ancho][this.largo];
    }
    
    public int getAncho() {
        return ancho;
    }
    public void setAncho(int ancho) {
        this.ancho = ancho;
    }
    public int getLargo() {
        return largo;
    }
    public void setLargo(int largo) {
        this.largo = largo;
    }
    public int getNumColores() {
        return numColores;
    }
    public void setNumColores(int numColores) {
        this.numColores = numColores;
    }
    
    public void validar() {
        if(getNumColores()<3) {
            
        }
    }
    
    public void mostrar() {
        for(int i=0;i<largo;i++) {
            for(int j =0;j<ancho;j++) {
                System.out.print(datos[i][j]+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }   
    }
    public  void rellenar(){ //rellena el matriz 1 al -20
        for(int i=0;i<ancho;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<largo;j++){
                datos[i][j]=(int)(Math.random()*numColores);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Qué problemas has tenido? Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

Se resuelve fácilmente recorriendo la fila y columna en la que estés y verificando que el numero que vayas a introducir no se repita el numero de veces que quieras.

```
public  void rellenar(){ //rellena el matriz 1 al -20
    for(int i=0;i<ancho;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<largo;j++){
            int num;
            boolean encontrado = false;
            do {
                int contadorAncho = 0;
                int contadorLargo = 0;
                num = (int)(Math.random()*numColores);
                //compruebas que no se repita en la fila
                for(int a=i; a>=0; a--) {
                    if(num == datos[a][j])
                        contadorAncho++;
                }
                //compruebas que no se repita en la columna
                for(int l=j; l>=0; l--) {
                    if(num == datos[i][l])
                        contadorLargo++;
                }
                if(contadorAncho<2 && contadorLargo<2)
                    encontrado = true;
            }while(!encontrado);
            datos[i][j] = num;
        }
    }
}
```